# Windows Phone 8 Html5 app JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I created a basic project using the "Windows Phone HTML5 App" template using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

In the default "index.html" page, if I paste the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
    <title>Windows Phone</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var sources = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            sources[i].addEventListener('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Error loading: '+e.target.src);
            });
        }(i));
    }
  </script>

    <div>
        <p>MY APPLICATION</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page-title">
        <p>page title</p>
      <div id="audio-container" >
        <audio controls="true" id="audio" src="Song1.mp3"></audio>
        <br />
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it shows a compiler error against the "<" sign in the "i < sources.length" statement:

Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character.

Why is the JavaScript code not being recognized? Do I need to surround it with some particular tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you paste it? What's in the rest of the file?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the HTML.

Comment: Actually, when I deployed the code in the emulator, it gives proper results. So it just seems to be some minor issue of settings in Visual Studio. Any idea what settings it could be?